# Intersection of two planes and another plane parallel to the intersection.

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I have two questions:

$1)$ How can I find the line of intersection between the planes

$$x+ 2y +z =4 \\ \mathrm{and}  \\ 2x+y-z=5$$

$2)$ How do I find an equation for a line that goes through $A = (2,0,2)$ and $B = (4,1,0)$ that is parallel to the answer in the first question?

I find the intuition on these problems really difficult, so if you describe how you do it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Some feedback never hurts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, you want to solve the system $$\begin{cases} x+ 2y +z =4 \\ 2x+y-z=5\end{cases}$$ for $(x,y,z)$. For example, summing I am getting that $x+y=3$. Then I am getting that $z=1-y$, so that $$(x,y,z)=(3-y,y,1-y)=(3,0,1)+y(-1,1,-1)$$ Thus, the intersection is a line $$\mathscr L:(3,0,1)+t(-1,1,-1)\;\;;\; t\in\Bbb R$$

For the second one, suppose we can write your line as $$\mathscr L':w+tv\;\;;\;t\in\Bbb R$$ for some vectors $v,w$. Saying that $\mathscr L'$ is parallel to the line we found above means their directions are parallel. Any line is fully determined by a point and a direction, you should be able to obtain what $\mathscr L'$ is. It seems the exercise wants two lines, one that goes through $A$ and one through $B$.

Recall that if we have a line $v+tw$ and we already know what $w$ is, and know that $v'$ is a point in it, we may let say $t=1$ so that $v+w=v'\implies w=v'-v$, that is, we may let $w$ be $v'$ plus any scalar multiple of the direction we want.

Comment: Thank you very much!

But how do you go from " x+y=3. Then I am getting that z=−y, so that " to giving the values 0 to both z and y?

My book gives the answers "1) x=t y=3-t og Z=-2+t" and "2) x+4y+3z-8=0"

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen Note that by replacing $x=3-y$ we get $3-y+2y+z=4$ so that $y+z=1\implies z=1-y$. Sorry about the slip. =)

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen Your book "solved for $x$", that is, it is getting $(x,y=3-x,z=x-2)$.

Comment: Thank you... how do I represent the second equation (the line A-B) as a parametric equation?

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen A line passing through $v$ with direction $w$ has equation $p(t)=v+wt$

Comment: can you explain it a bit simpler? What steps do I have to do with two points A =(1,0,0) and B =(2,3,3) for example, to represent the line A-B.

Comment: @KaizervonMaanen As I just said, I think the exercise wants you to write the equation of two lines, one passing trough $A$, another passing through $B$, but both with direction paralell to $(-1,1-1)$.